# ValueError: too many values to unpack (while reducing with foldByKey)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, fold

struggling with "ValueError: too many values to unpack" error, while running the code bellow, the intent is to build a histogram of values for each key:

```
%pyspark

import datetime
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

def featVecSms( x ):
    sttm = datetime.datetime.strptime( x[1], '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%f' )
    hourOfDay = int( sttm.strftime( '%H' ) )
    dayOfWeek = int( sttm.strftime( '%w' ) )
    dayOfMonth = int( sttm.strftime( '%d' ) )
    duration = datetime.datetime.strptime( x[2], '%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.%f' ) - sttm
    duration = duration.total_seconds()
    service = x[3]
    resultCode = int( x[4] )
    msc = x[5]
    actionMap = {
        "0":'fsm',
        "1":'fsm',
        "2000":'sri',
        "2001":'sri',
        "2100":'sri',
        "2101":'sri',
        "2102":'fsm',
        "2200":'sri',
        "2201":'sri',
        "2202":'fsm',
        "2203":'fsm',
        "2204":'fsm',
        "2205":'fsm',
        "2206":'fsm',
        "2207":'sri',
        "2208":'sri',
        "2209":'sri',
        "2210":'fsm',
        "2211":'fsm',
        "2212":'fsm',
        "2213":'fsm',
        "2214":'fsm',
        "2215":'sri',
        "2216":'fsm'
    }
    action = actionMap.get( x[4] )
    return ( x[0], hourOfDay, dayOfWeek, dayOfMonth, duration, service, resultCode,  msc, action )

textFile = sc.textFile("/export/sampleMsesAll.txt")
enTuples = textFile.map(lambda x: x.split("', u'"))
msRec = enTuples.map( featVecSms )

def countByCrit( accVal, currVal, idx ):
    accVal[ int( currVal[ idx ] ) ] = accVal( [ int( currVal[ idx ] ) ] ) + 1
    return accVal

def countByTod( accVal, currVal ):
    return countByCrit( accVal, currVal, 1 )

todmap = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
msTodSuccess = msRec.filter( lambda x: x[2] >= 0 ).foldByKey( todmap, countByTod )
#.map( lambda x: ( x[0], reduce( lambda x,y: x + str(y), x[2], "" ) ) )

msTodSuccess.collect()
```

The error bellow is thrown:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 52.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 52.0 (TID 115, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/export/edrsSmartRetry/code/spark-1.5.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/export/edrsSmartRetry/code/spark-1.5.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/export/edrsSmartRetry/code/spark-1.5.2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2355, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/export/edrsSmartRetry/code/spark-1.5.2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2355, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/export/edrsSmartRetry/code/spark-1.5.2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/export/edrsSmartRetry/code/spark-1.5.2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1780, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/export/edrsSmartRetry/code/spark-1.5.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 266, in mergeValues
    for k, v in iterator:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

The data looks like this:

```
$ head -15 /export/sampleMses10M.txt/part-00000 
(u'263775998314', u'20151119T180719.000349', u'20151120T074928.837095', u'GoodMorning', u'2210', u'263775998314')
(u'263779563529', u'20151119T181318.000201', u'20151120T122346.432229', u'GoodMorning', u'2204', u'undefined')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T092503.000629', u'20151120T111833.430649', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T092316.000331', u'20151120T125251.794699', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T092621.000557', u'20151120T125514.904726', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T092621.000557', u'20151120T135521.395529', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T092503.000629', u'20151120T145418.069707', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T092621.000557', u'20151120T145526.133207', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T154208.000410', u'20151120T154345.379585', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T154319.000636', u'20151120T154647.354102', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T154406.000245', u'20151120T154904.993095', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T154319.000636', u'20151120T164653.173588', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263783104169', u'20151120T154406.000245', u'20151120T164909.888433', u'Strangenet', u'2215', u'263770010027')
(u'263774918225', u'20151120T090505.000269', u'20151120T102248.630188', u'StrangeCash', u'0', u'263770010027')
(u'263782099158', u'20151119T182038.000537', u'20151120T064040.240860', u'GoodMorning', u'0', u'263770010500')
```

There are only 123k samples but there should be tens of million of records in application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem with your code is that you got the types wrong.

First of all `*byKey` methods operate on `PairwiseRDDs`. In Python it means RDD which contains tuples of length 2 or other structure (lets call it `pair`) which can be unpacked like this:

```
k, v = pair
```

`msRec`, which contains elements of length 9,  clearly won't work here.

The second issue is that you use wrong transformation. Let's take a look at the signature of `foldByKey` in Scala.:

```
def foldByKey(zeroValue: V)(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

where `V` is a type of the values (`RDD[(K, V)]`). As you can see `zeroValue` and returned type of the function should be the same as the type of the values which is clearly not the case here.

If result type is different than input type you should use either `combineByKey` or `aggregateByKey`.

Comment: Happy New Year buddy!

Comment: @eliasah Likewise :)

Comment: Well explained! I had figured it out, but got caught up in new year celebrations and forgot to come back to update the post...